# badrequest response from server when it currect

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-http, angular-httpclient

i need to create a register page .

when i need to send data from angular6 to server it how me this Error :

> :44390/api/role/CreateRole:1 POST https://localhost:44390/api/role/CreateRole 400 (Bad Request)
>           role-service.service.ts:96 HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "https://localhost:44390/api/role/CreateRole", ok: false, …}
>           (anonymous) @ role-service.service.ts:96
>           push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error @ catchError.js:33
>           role-service.service.ts:102 addrole failed: Http failure response for https://localhost:44390/api/role/CreateRole: 400 Bad Request

this address it currect . `https://localhost:44390/api/role/CreateRole`

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

**this my code :**

**Register.ts**

```
AddUser(){
console.log(this.register);
this.userService.RegisterUser(this.register).subscribe((data)=>{
  console.log(data)
});
```

}

**Service :**

```
    baseUrl="https://localhost:44390/api/register/";
   user:IUser;
   private headers:HttpHeaders;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.headers=new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
   }

  /*
  ********************************
  ******** Register User *********
  ********************************
  */
  public RegisterUser(user:IRegister):Observable<IRegister>{
    console.log(this.baseUrl+'RegisterUser',user,{headers:this.headers});
    return this.http.post<IRegister>(this.baseUrl+'RegisterUser',user,{headers:this.headers}).pipe(
      tap((register: IRegister) => this.log(`register user w/ email=${register.email}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<IRegister>('register user'))
    );
  }
```

Comment: This looks like the error is on the server side. You should debug the service to see where the issue is there.

Comment: server is good work